# How to print pdf-file from stream in vaadin 7?

Tags: java, pdf, xslt, vaadin, apache-fop

I am trying to print a pdf straight from the stream in vaadin 7 using Apache FOP + xsl. At the moment I can successfully create new xml document and regenerate pdf-file from it using xsl fo. I save the file to the server and everything is looking good.

My problem is that it is not possible to save file to the server, so I need to read it to some kind of bytearray and then open it when user is clicking "Print"-button.

```
out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(
        "/testPrint.pdf");

try {
    // Construct fop with desired output format
    Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, out);

    // XSL
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer =
            factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource("printTemplate.xsl"));

    Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

    //xml->xsl-fo-->pdf
    transformer.transform(xml, res);
} finally {
    out.close();
}
```

When user clicks the print button, the generated pdf-document looks good after that when I check it from the server.

```
 print.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {

@Override
public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event)
{
    PdfComponent pdf = new PdfComponent(lang, bookingDto);

    try {
        DOMSource xml = pdf.getXMLSource(bookingDto, lang);
        pdf.convertToPDF(lang,xml);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
});
```

**QUESTION**

How can I get the PDF document to a stream and how can I get it open automatically in a browser when user clicks the print button in Vaadin 7 application without saving the file to a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloading files in Vaadin works as described [here](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Letting+the+user+download+a+file). Summary:

```
Button downloadButton = new Button("Download image");
StreamResource myResource = createResource();
FileDownloader fileDownloader = new FileDownloader(myResource);
fileDownloader.extend(downloadButton);
```

Then your `StreamResource` provides an `InputStream` that contains the file data. So, you don't need to save the file on the server. Regarding the printing, I don't know if it is even possible to instruct the browser open the print dialog directly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I got ByteArrayOutputStream from the Apache FOP transformer. is there any way to get a StreamResource somehow from the outputstream? I got a stream when user clicks the print button.

Comment: Have a look at the linked wiki page, the code example does it: `new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray())` where `bos` is the `ByteArrayOutputStream `

Comment: Thanks Steffen. Now I got it working partly. User has to click twice the button to get pdf-file to download.

Answer (score 0):

I once developed something based on this and it followed the steps below:

- Pass the input data as xml from front end to server side (you could use ajax).
- In the server side, use fop to create your pdf file, save the pdf file somewhere (probably in a folder).
- Make another call from the front end to get the pdf file and display.
  Not sure if this is how it is written in vaadin, but it is somewhat like this:

  ```
  pdffile = "\\path\\"+pdfname+".pdf"
  file = new File(pdffile)
  response.setContentType("application/pdf")
  response.setHeader("Content-disposition" , "inline;   filename=${file.getName()}")
  response.outputStream << file.newInputStream()
  ```

Hope this helps.